# iPad application always opens in portrait mode

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

The app uses a UISplitView and it always opens in portrait mode.  If the iPad is held horizontally it will open in portrait mode and then rotate to landscape.  I'd like it to just open up in landscape mode without needing to rotate.  Any ideas>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Info.plist, set `UIInterfaceOrientation` to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` (or Left). See the [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) for more details including how to have different orientations for iPhone versus iPad.

Comment: OK Great.  But now I have the opposite problem.   How can I get the app to just open up in the orientation the user is holding it?  I want it to open in landscape if they are holding it horizontally and portrait if they are holding it vertically.  With your change if I'm holding it vertically the app will open up in landscape and then rotate to portrait mode.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out.  You just need to add the "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" key and add all 4 orientations.  Thanks for pointing me to the plist.